# Congruence equation for modulus 2

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Suppose $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Is the equation

$$((a+n)(b+n)) mod_2 = ((a-n)(b-n)) mod_2$$

satisfied?

This is not a homework or such. (I'm not a student) I need to decide
if two signs are equal. Unfortunately I don't know really how to solve these
kind of congruence equations.

Although I ultimately only need the answer, a derivation would however be nice, too.

Comment: The left hand side minus the right hand side is a multiple of $2$.

Comment: You mean without the modulus. All right. And since $(a+b)mod_n= (a\,mod_n + b\, mod_n)mod_n$ this gives the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the LHS 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned} 
((a+n)(b+n))mod_2  =& (ab+an+bn+n^2)mod_2 \\ =&(ab-an-bn +n^2)mod_2 \\ =&((a-n)(b-n))mod_2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Where we have used the fact that $(-x)mod_2 = (x)mod_2$}

Answer (score 0):

It's always true. Using elementary identities you can simplify $$((a+n)(b+n)) mod_2 = ((a-n)(b-n)) mod_2
$$

$$(a*b + n^2 + a*n+b*n) mod_2 = (a*b+n^2-a*n-b*n) mod_2 
\\as\ n^2 and \ a*b\ are\ contribute\  same\ you \ can \ cancel \ them
$$
$$(a*n+b*n) mod_2 = (-a*n-b*n) mod_2 
\\ if \ n \ is \ even\ equality \ is \ obvious\ otherwise
\\(a+b) mod_2 = (-a-b) mod_2 
\\now \ suppose \ this \ equality \ doesn't \ hold
\\ (a+b+a+b) mod_2 = 1 => 2(a+b)mod_2 = 1 => contradiction
$$
therefore this equality holds for all $$a,b\in\mathbb{Z} \ and \ n\in\mathbb{N}  $$

Comment: Thanks. Peters answer came a little faster